# Android Studio - Cannot see an option to create AVD or SDK Manager

Tags: android-studio, react-native

This is my first time using Android Studio, and i probably am missing something silly.
On following the React Native getting started guide - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html , I remember i did setup the Android SDK, HAXM and virtual device. But i don't see any such options on my Android Studio.

Some screenshots -

AVD is not present under Tools -

[image]

On Help>Find action , there is no "sdk manager"[image]

Appearance & Behavior → System Settings does not have "Android SDK" either.

[image]

Also i see this message at the bottom. Im not even trying to save anyting, this just popps up when i start Android Studio -

[image]

I'm on a windows machine currently, the project "AwesomeProject" is created using react-native cli.. and i've tried reinstalling Android Studio too. Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something broke when i closed the amulator via the windows task manager. What i did then was manually delete android studio (shift+delete).. then installed Android Studio normally, and the SDKs. 
Now things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set android home and path in your bash then you can access the sdk manager and avd from the terminal.
For avd - 'android avd'
For sdk manager - 'android'